# apply styling only to a specific url

Tags: urls

I want to apply styling only to a page with a specific URL(not id) in Wordpress. 
for example to .../something/events
kindly suggest only PHP solutions, via funtion.php (not CSS id or class)
I've tried different things but nothing has worked. thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Why don't you add a class to body via functions if you are on that url, so you can use that class on css, like so:

```
function add_class_to_body($classes) {
    if(is_page('events')){
        $classes[] = 'page-events';
        return $classes;
    }
}
add_filter('body_class','add_class_to_body');
```

Then you are able to target through

```
.page-events div{
    background-color: red;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your solution. I'm sure it will work, but the problem is I have a multilingual website, and there is a problem with a plugin and that I can not translate the slug for some reason (although I have tried so hard to make it happen, and failed). so there's an .../event page and another .../fa/event page, which with your solution there will be no difference if I'm right. The first .../event page works fine. the problem is the second which have a same slug but different url.

Comment: I'm sure that if you had added that piece of information to your question that I'd have given a different answer as well. Did you try the code? I'm not sure that even with the translation plugin that the page would be identified

Answer (score 0):

I found this somewhere out of the blue and it worked! so I share this in case it helps anyone

```
add_action( 'init', 'apply_css_if_url_contains_string' );

function apply_css_if_url_contains_string() {

$url = $_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'] . $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];

if ( false !== strrpos( $url, 'events' ) ) {
echo '<style type="text/css">
     body { font-size: 50px!important }
     </style>';
} 

}
```